# Kotlin compilation fails in Terminal but not Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, compiler-errors

I have the following imports in a class:

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient
import java.net.http.HttpRequest
import java.net.http.HttpResponse
```

When I build inside of Intellij, the dependencies are properly resolved and there are no issues. When I run CI in GitHub Actions, there are also no issues.

However, when I run ./gradlew clean build in my macos terminal, it is unable to resolve the dependencies above. It fails on the compileKotlin step.

The following is my build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.60'
}

group 'com.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {

    // kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

    // gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // testing
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')
    testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`java.net.http`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) API was introduced in JDK 11. The reason you're getting the unresolved reference error when running Gradle build from terminal is most likely the lower version of JDK being used there.

By default, `compileKotlin` task uses the same JDK as the one that was used to start a Gradle build itself.

Gradle detects the path to JDK either by `JAVA_HOME` environment variable or by looking for `java` command in the PATH. So the most reliable way to specify JDK for Gradle is to set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in terminal to the desired JDK path.

Alternatively, `compileKotlin` task can use JDK different from the default one in Gradle. So for example, it can compile for JDK 11 even when Gradle runs with JDK 8. This is set with the `jdkHome` compiler option:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jdkHome = "path_to_jdk_here"
}
```

See the other options for Kotlin/JVM compile task here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#attributes-specific-for-jvm